# Assigning AVAudioRecorderDelegate to non UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I'm creating an iOS application that starts recording audio when a prompt occurs rather than when a button is pressed. Because of this, I've put the AVAudioRecorder in a scheduler object that is called from it's own class. However, when I assign the **scheduler as the delegate for the recorder**, I get the warning Assigning to `'id<AVAudioRecorderDelegate>' from incompatible type 'LWPScheduler *__strong'`. Here is the implementation for the scheduler:

```
@implementation LWPScheduler
@synthesize tempo;
@synthesize userName;

+(LWPScheduler *)masterScheduler{
    static LWPScheduler *masterScheduler = nil;
    if (masterScheduler == nil)
    {
        masterScheduler = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return masterScheduler;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tempo = 120;
        self.userName = @"Tim Burland";

        //recording init
        // Set the audio file
        NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                                   @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                                   nil];
        NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

        //audio session
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

        //recorder settings
        NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        // Initiate and prepare the recorder
        _recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
        _recorder.delegate = self; //Incompatible Type Warning Here
        _recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [_recorder prepareToRecord];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

My question is whether I have to migrate the audio handling to the controller for the view the recorder would be contained in. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ancillary question: What is the term for an object that lives in it's own class file?

Comment: I don't understand the ancillary question...

Comment: For example, the `[NSFileManager defaultManager]`, or in this case, the `[LWPScheduler masterScheduler]`

Comment: These are referred to as shared instances.  The object doesn't live in its own class file... you still use it from other class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your interface (or private class extension) tell the compiler that your are conforming to the protocol the delegate expects. For e.g.:

```
@interface LWPScheduler : NSObject <AVAudioRecorderDelegate>
// ...
@end
```

The protocol defines required and/or optional methods you may have to implement (Xcode will warn you about the required one). After telling the interface the class confirms to the protocol, `_recorder.delegate = self;` will just work.